ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'einops'
I'm tring to run the code on dust3r
I have already installed einops
Attempted the following two methods separately.
pip install einops
conda install einops

and successfully install the einops (I think)
PS E:\dust3r> pip show einops
Name: einops
Version: 0.8.0
Summary: A new flavour of deep learning operations
Home-page: 
Author: Alex Rogozhnikov
Author-email: 
License: MIT
Location: C:\Users\15805\anaconda3\Lib\site-packages
Requires:
Required-by:

but when I try to run
python3 demo.py --model_name DUSt3R_ViTLarge_BaseDecoder_512_dpt

It told me that
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "E:\dust3r\demo.py", line 12, in <module>
    from dust3r.model import AsymmetricCroCo3DStereo
  File "E:\dust3r\dust3r\model.py", line 14, in <module>
    from .heads import head_factory
  File "E:\dust3r\dust3r\heads\__init__.py", line 8, in <module>
    from .dpt_head import create_dpt_head
  File "E:\dust3r\dust3r\heads\dpt_head.py", line 11, in <module>
    from einops import rearrange
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'einops'

How can I solve this

The most common cause of this is that your "pip" is from a different version than your Python.  Try python -m pip install einops.

Try using conda to install your packages: conda install conda-forge::einops
